# Laravel 5.4 migration

Tags: laravel, migration

I am developing a school management system with Laravel 5.4. When I migrate the the database table I get this error msg:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Parse error:
>   syntax error, unexpected '100' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ')'

Please help me, how do I solve this error?

Migration:

```
public function up() { 
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) { 
$table->increments('student_id'); $table->string('first_name',50); $table->string('last_name',50); $table->date('dob'); 
$table->string('100')->nullable(); $table->string('status'); 
$table->string('current_address',255)->nullable(); 
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users‌​'); 
//$table->timestamps(); 
}); }
```

Comment: I am trying many times and checking my table schema

Comment: I mean please share some of your work with us.

Comment: It is a database table

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('student_id');
            $table->string('first_name',50);
            $table->string('last_name',50);
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->string('100')->nullable();
            $table->string('status');
            $table->string('current_address',255)->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
            //$table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: Don't add it as a comment, edit your question and add the migration file there.

Comment: Give a name into the parenthesis $table->string('100')->nullable();
example: string('name',100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed:

```
$table->string('100')->nullable();
```

you probably where trying to do something like this :

```
$table->string('somestring', 100)->nullable();
```

Comment: I correction this field but its not work,,,,,,getting same error message

Comment: Did you rerun your migrations after your change?

Comment: Yes, After change I do migrations this database

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are using a mysql database, In mysql database column names cannot be of full numeric characters, unless you put them in quotes. refer the [doc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).
which says,

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

I think it is a typo from your side. If you really want to want to name your column `100` consider renaming it to  `field100` or something like that.